# How do you console.log in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I spent hours on this and can't find a way to do the most basic thing like put `console.log("la");` in my code and print it **inside** **Atom** when i view the html with `html preview` package.

I used to have one called `console-js` and right click on the `html preview` to launch it, but now, right click does nothing, and this package has some bug that i can't fix `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedText' of undefined`

I was offered a few packages that has nothing to do with my need :

```
Script
Console-log
Platformio IDE terminal
Console.
```

I just can't find a simple way to print a simple thing while running my code inside Atom ( means viewing an html page with `Javascript`).

Is there a package that do such a simple thing ?

Comment: check this out 
https://atom.io/packages/atom-console

Comment: Atom is built upon Chromium, so it has the same developer tools as the Chrome browser. The [evaluate](https://atom.io/packages/evaluate) automatically opens the DecTools console when you run code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this:

View -> Developer -> Toggle Developer Tools

[image: Example of console.log in Atom]

Comment: Isn't every Atom user a developer? I mean isn't that what the program is used for, developing things?